# Slug function removing letters with url accent

Tags: php, slug

The function below is working, but I can not understand the reason for being switched by excluding letters that have special characters:

```
   function slug( $string, $separator = '-' ) {
        $accents_regex = '~&([a-z]{1,2})(?:acute|cedil|circ|grave|lig|orn|ring|slash|th|tilde|uml);~i';
        $special_cases = array( '&' => 'and', "'" => '');
        $string = mb_strtolower( trim( $string ), 'UTF-8' );
        $string = str_replace( array_keys($special_cases), array_values( $special_cases), $string );
        $string = preg_replace( $accents_regex, '$1', htmlentities( $string, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8' ) );
        $string = preg_replace("/\s+/", "$separator", $string);
        $string = preg_replace("/[$separator]+/u", "$separator", $string);
        return $string;
    }
```

example:

the string: `"um rádio bonito"`

the result should be: `"um-radio-bonito"`

but the result is: `"um-rdio-bonito"`

Comment: @Nick Thanks, I removed the third and fifth lines, but still the error persists

Comment: @Nick I do not know if the error is related to php7 because almost all slug codes that I tested have some similar error

Comment: Actually @Gislef my original comment is incorrect as htmlentities will put `&`s into the string

Comment: Your code works fine on all versions of PHP since 5.3.29... https://3v4l.org/WKuAV

Comment: @Nick I changed the server to php 5.5 the error continues

Comment: It works on PHP5.5 on the demo link for your sample data...

Comment: @Nick yes I saw, thank you, but I really do not know what happens

Comment: Unfortunately since I don't have access to your server I can't really tell what might be wrong, as the code does seem to work fine. I would suggest echo'ing the value of `$string` after each stage to see if something obvious shows up.

Comment: @Nick `print_r($slug)` return `�` in special characters, before going through the function

Comment: `utf8_encode($slug)`  It worked! :) again many thanks @Nick

Comment: That's great! I'm glad you got it to work.

Answer (score 1):

This function can help you

```
function cleanAccents($r)
{
    $r = preg_replace("/ß/","ss", $r);
    $r = preg_replace("/[àáâãäå]/","a", $r);
    $r = preg_replace("/æ/","ae", $r);
    $r = preg_replace("/ç/","c", $r);
    $r = preg_replace("/[èéêë]/","e", $r);
    $r = preg_replace("/[ìíîï]/","i", $r);
    $r = preg_replace("/ñ/","n", $r);
    $r = preg_replace("/[òóôõö]/","o", $r);
    $r = preg_replace("/œ/","oe", $r);
    $r = preg_replace("/[ùúûü]/","u", $r);
    $r = preg_replace("/[ýÿ]/","y", $r);        
    return $r;
}
```